# How do you make a 404 page?

Tags: http-status-code-404

I thought of making a 404 Page. but it seems hard.. how do i do it?

## Here's what I did:

1. Made `.htaccess` File
2. Put: `ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html` inside of the `.htaccess` file..
3. Added `css` design

## Why doesn't it work?

I use [glitch](https://glitch.com) as my coding website. Is that the problem?
Is there an alternative way to do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a custom 404 page for an app on Glitch, you'll need to be building a Node/full-stack app and configuring the page in your server-side code.

For example, I've got this simple Express app that sends any non-index route request to a 404 page: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tranquil-hurricane-friction?path=server.js%3A25%3A0